# Comparison of performance, connection time and security between different SSH ciphers?

Tags: ssh, performance

I am looking for a table comparison between SSH ciphers, as I do want to know if I can speed-up two things:

- initial connection time, especially when using key authentication (rsa)
- file transfer speed

Answer (score 2):

Nezt time check Google first "ssh+chipher+comparsion+speed":

- http://blog.famzah.net/2010/06/11/openssh-ciphers-performance-benchmark/
- http://mrpointy.wordpress.com/2008/07/01/openssh-crypto-cipher-performance/

Comment: Thanks, I am ware about this page but still, it doesn't say anything about initial connection time and security, these are still open-questions.

Comment: Ironically, this answer is now one of google's favorite links for answering the above question!

Answer (score 0):

The speediest approach for file transfer is to disable encryption entirely. This is detailed in my answer at: [Copying files between linux machines with strong authentication without encryption](https://serverfault.com/questions/452978/copying-files-between-linux-machines-with-strong-authentication-but-without-encr/453095#453095)

Short of that, I make use of the `arcfour` cipher.