# Possible to kill command after a timeout if not success?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, bash, freebsd

I would like to use `mbuffer` to do ZFS replication with, but in order to do that, I have to start it in listening mode on the target host. That I would do from the master host by

```
ssh 10.10.10.11 mbuffer -s 128k -m 1G -I 9090 | zfs receive tank3/pro4
```

`mbuffer` will never timeout, but exit with success when a replication have completed.

**Question**

It is possible to timeout `mbuffer` if it haven't returned success within e.g. 2 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [timelimit](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/timelimit) utility in FreeBSD ports to limit execution time of any command. If timeout fired, command will be killed.

Comment: timeout is a similar utility for linux (at least debian and the like)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a wrapper script to start the mbuffer process, record the PID associated with mbuffer, have the script sleep for 2 minutes then if the PID is still in existence, TERM kill the PID.

Answer (score 1):

You could also initiate mbuffer through an all-in-one command that uses SSH as a transport. Not an issue if the destination is remote... more of a performance penalty if it's local...

> zfs send tank3/pro4@snapshot | mbuffer -q -v 0 -s 128k -m 1G | ssh
>   root@10.10.10.11 'mbuffer -s 128k -m 1G | zfs receive tank3/pro4'

If performance is an issue, you may be bound by CPU and SSH encryption. [There are a couple of workarounds for that...](https://serverfault.com/questions/452978/copying-files-between-linux-machines-with-strong-authentication-without-encrypti/453095#453095)