# How to mount remote directory with authentication, but without encryption?

Tags: ssh, backup, nfs, rsync

I have 2 servers that are connected over the internet (not a secure connection), A and B. I'd like to mount a folder from B on server A for the purpose of later generating and transferring a lot of files from A to B, there will be nothing transferred from B to A.

The number and size of files is high, so I'd like to sacrifice encryption for speed, but since both servers are internet-accessible, I still need some sort of authentication.

I've tried sshfs, but the speed was abysmally bad compared to rsync, I've tried a bunch of settings to make it faster, but it didn't help much, esp. since arcfour encryption seems to be removed from ssh now.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Disclaimer: I have seen [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/452978/copying-files-between-linux-machines-with-strong-authentication-without-encrypti) post, but it's about transferring already existing files (for which rsync works fine for me), I'd like to generate and transfer files without saving them locally first.

Comment: **Samba** (CIFS) shares are authenticated username/password but not encrypted and **NFS** shares traditionally support IP-address based access controls only although from NFSv4 username/password authentication and encryption is possible too, but that requires first settings up Kerberos. But most VPN solutions offer very good performance and will provide transport encryption when you run a n otherwise clear text protocol. Use your firewall to provide extra security

Comment: If you need authentication, what makes you think you don't also need encryption? I understand the performance hit, but I would highly recommend that you always encrypt your data. Also, why can you not save them to the disk first? Have you tried using regular FTP? I would recommend vsftpd, https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html

Comment: FTP over SSH, SFTP and FTPS seem like options

Comment: @HBruijn you don't want to use CIFS over the internet. the protocol is very chatty and therefore slow over long distances