# Possibility of WAN Optimization for SSH traffic

Tags: ssh, rsync, optimization, wide-area-network

While I do understand that SSH by itself is a very low bandwidth utilizing protocol, it is sometimes choking up bandwidth during peak hours in our office environment. I want to know if at all it is possible to reduce/optimize SSH (rsync) traffic over WAN ?

I realized that riverbed cannot do it. What kind of other designs (proxies) can I possible think of, ignoring security issues like MiTM, DPI, etc. Can TrafficSqueezer, WANProxy or OpenNOP be of any use here ?

Also, please suggest if there are any other ideas to backup data (if there is any) other than rsync. Is it even possible that I think of decrypting SSH with a proxy server before reaching Riverbed and transporting it over WAN to the other end.

```
Sender (RSYNC) Server --> Proxy (Decrypt SSH) --> Sending Riverbed --> Receiving Riverbed --> Receiver Server
```

Current Topology:

```
100's of Users (rsync) --> Source Riverbed --> (passed through traffic/unoptimized)  -->  Destination Riverbed --> Remote Machine
```

Comment: Related: [Why is my rsync so slow?](http://serverfault.com/q/377598/126632)

Comment: From a security point of view, even if you can do it, you really really shouldn't.

Comment: Can you give some additional information about your source systems, destination systems, the bandwidth and nature of the data being transferred?

Comment: I mean to say, what are you backing up, and why is the current situation a problem?

Comment: Users are backing up Binary Source Code Builds. The target is half way on the other end of the world. This happens to and fro and hence the load on the bandwidth. Comparatively we have a very thin WAN link - 400 Mbps. They are probably running rsync with -avuz options alone as the developers do not care about the bandwidth.

Comment: No, they shouldn't be doing this. They should rsync to a _local_ server, which you then mirror, backup, etc., to the remote location. You should have a much easier time optimizing that.

Comment: If Riverbed can't compress/optimize it then nobody can. And if this MPLS, why not just implement a proper QoS policy on it to shape any kind of ssh/rsync traffic?

Answer (score 3):

I was initially going to be a naysayer to the idea of trying to "WAN optimize" rsync traffic, but the more I thought about it the more I decided that it was possible.

A TCP-based dictionary compressor (which I believe the Riverbed Steelhead appliances can do) would probably benefit an unencrypted rsync stream. Presumably the Riverbed devices can do encryption on the "optimized" traffic, so running rsync unencrypted shouldn't be compromising the integrity or confidentiality of traffic to the WAN. (Between the source server and the Riverbed device may be a different story.)

You don't have to run rsync over SSH. It will run perfectly fine over TCP or any other reliable stream transport.

It seems like a good WAN acceleration architecture would run somewhat counter to a good security architecture, since encrypted traffic would be high-entropy and low redundancy and not at all conducive to compression. I think these are concerns you'd have to balance. I haven't kept up with Riverbed in a number of years, but this actually seems like a place where man-in-the-middle decryption of encrypted protocols might make good sense (albeit that turns the WAN accelerator into a *huge* target for attacks).

Edit:

I'm coming back to this answer a few hours later because, frankly, it's keeping me up at night.

I want to clarify some assumptions that I'm making. I am assuming:

- You're working with WAN links that are significantly slower than a LAN-- 100Mbps or less.
- You're performing backups across these WAN links that you'd like to speed-up, in terms of wallclock time.
- The servers hosting the source and destination files have sufficient CPU and network connectivity to completely saturate the WAN link and the WAN really is the bottleneck.
- You're using operating systems with TCP implementations that can reasonably scale the receive window to accommodate the bandwith delay product of your WAN link.

If the servers can't saturate the network link then your bottleneck is somewhere else. Basically, I'm assuming that you've got a small pipe that your servers can saturate when running backups. If you're bottlenecking on CPU or I/O in the servers then no amount of network-related "magic" is going to help you.

Speaking rather bluntly, I feel a bit silly speaking positively about WAN acceleration appliances. I've been less than impressed with them in the past (mainly from an ROI and cost perspective) and wary of them after hearing numerous horror stories about application and operating system "strangeness" that would disappear when the WAN accelerators were disabled. I've been suspicious of them as a "technology" and generally have felt like they are a symptom of using poorly-engineered protocols, poor server-placement decisions, or poor network architecture.

I've spent the better part of two hours reading-up on dictionary-based protocol compressors and playing around with rsync. I think that, depending on the amount of redundancy in the changes you're synchronizing with rsync, there's actually a potential for seeing some minor performance improvement using a dictionary-based WAN accelerator. It's going to depend a lot on what your data looks like.

I don't have any numbers using an actual WAN accelerator to back that up. Nor do I have any personal experience with WAN accelerators in production use, let alone "accelerating" the rsync protocol. I certainly wouldn't go out and buy something based on what I'm saying here, but if you already have something in place I'd consider running some unencrypted rsync traffic through it to see what it does.

Comment: The WAN links are MPLS & 400Mb wide. So, security shouldn't be an issue. Even in the worst case, we could encrypt/decrypt rsync traffic by sender/receiver Riverbeds. CPU & I/O too is not a problem. The ed users initiating transfers usually use Win7 or Linux (Ubuntu) machines. I hope these OS's can adapt to the BDP (I'm not sure though). The 400 Mbps line has all kind of traffic. But it is SSH traffic alone that chokes it (70% of link) as it passes through Riverbeds unoptimized. The solution I'm looking for is to compress/optimize the data, not speed it up as the link speed is fixed for now.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the rsync over other reliable protocols a bit as that answers the issue more accurately. I am also looking at the UDR/UDT solution suggested by ewwhite Please also keep in mind that I it gets difficult (not impossible) to ask hundreds of end-users to install or change their "best" practices.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely see the answers at: [Why is my rsync so slow?](https://serverfault.com/questions/377598/why-is-my-rsync-so-slow)

I've relied on rsync-based solutions for replication and backup for many years. I've never needed to use any form of WAN acceleration (using an appliance).

Over the years, my rsync approaches have evolved; from basic compression to using "-e ssh -c arcfour" as a lighter-weight cipher, to using [HPN-SSH](http://www.psc.edu/index.php/hpn-ssh) to be able to control TCP windows and disable encryption over longer distance links, and most recently, [wrapping rsync with UDR/UDT](https://github.com/LabAdvComp/UDR) to have UDP-based rsync transfers. I should add that **[UDT](http://udt.sourceforge.net)** is the core of [some WAN-acceleration productions](http://udt.sourceforge.net/poweredby.html) on the market.

These are pretty esoteric solutions, but I'd really start with understanding what you're doing today. Let's see your current rsync command strings and try to see if they can be optimized.

- What are you backing up?
- How far is the target from the source?
- What are your bandwidth capabilities/limitations?

***Edit:***

You're talking about binary data being transferred over a long distance with a bandwidth capability of 400Mbps. And this appears to be [multiple streams of bidirectional traffic](https://serverfault.com/questions/637990/possibility-of-wan-optimization-for-ssh-traffic/638065#comment769044_638065) triggered at random times of the day.

If bandwidth saturation is your concern, couldn't you simply rate-limit your rsync transfers with:

```
--bwlimit=KBPS          limit I/O bandwidth; KBytes per second
```

Or if your network devices are capable, this could become a traffic-shaping or [quality-of-service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) exercise. But in the end, it seems like it's a people/policy issue.

***Edit:***

My suggestion for [UDR](https://github.com/LabAdvComp/UDR) sends rsync unencrypted by default over UDP ports 9000-9100. This doesn't require much of a change in the command line, versus running rsync in daemon mode. That *is* possibly within the realm of something that can be addressed by your Riverbed units. It wasn't clear from your initial question as to the scope, number of users or if you even had the WAN accelerators in place.

Comment: Users are backing up Binary Source Code Builds. The target is half way on the other end of the world. This happens to and fro and hence the load on the bandwidth. Comparatively we have a very thin WAN link - 400 Mbps. They are probably running rsync with -avuz options alone as the developers do not care about the bandwidth.

Comment: @deppfx Given that, I should also ask about the size of the transfers and whether this is a private communications link. Native rsync over ssh (and scp) won't run optimally over that type of distance/bandwidth, so dropping encryption may be a helpful option. Maybe you *should* look into the [UDR/UDT solution](https://github.com/LabAdvComp/UDR) I mentioned in my answer, as it's exactly what I use for this type of transfer...

Comment: Like I said, the --bwlimit switch is not an option as every team would want their transfer to be completed as fast as possible and I'm talking about easily around 10 - 100 GB data moving to-and-fro every day/night. They just wouldn't care. I am going through your solution now.

Comment: @deppfx This is why more detail is always better... you have lots (hundreds?) of end-users each (*manually*) triggering rsyncs of compiled code bidirectionally across your WAN link to the point where it's negatively impacting communications? Is there a network engineer in the house? Is this more of a "people problem" or policy issue than something that needs a technology solution? What type of firm is this? Has this been a problem for a long time?

Comment: @ewwhite.You are right.100's of users manually trigger rsync bidirectionally across WAN. Other traffic like http,dns,ssl is optimized by the riverbeds.But riverbed cant optimize ssh traffic by design and this is choking bandwidth at various times of the day.There is a network team and we are trying to figure out how to combat this problem.Increasing bandwidth to 1 Gbps is under discussions but I want to figure out if there is a way to optimize all this rsync traffic. Ideally using version control software is the way to go. But that's another story altogether.

Comment: @deppfx - Admittedly, I don't know your topology, but on the surface it sounds like mirroring the data being synchronized onto a single rsync server on each side of the WAN link would alleviate a lot of the bandwidth usage on the WAN link.

Comment: @EvanAnderson: Added the current topology to the question.