# Replicating storage efficiently

Tags: linux, storage, replication

I want to replicate in the region of 10Tb of data (*lots* of smallish files, low level of churn) across a WAN with minimal impact on the available infrastructure.

While I could simply use rsync, this means looking for the changes and comparing the local and remote data (disk I/O, network bandwidth and CPU costs) although rsync does this efficiently, I wonder of there is a more efficient solution which can track changes and propagate them (preferably bidirectionally).

The storage itself is iSCSI on HP NAS devices. We have looked previously at using its built-in replication capabilities but found them to be slow and unreliable.

DRBD mirrors would require additional hardware at both ends. Which would be rather expensive. I've also been bitten by DRBD replication failures in the past.

Would glusterfs be more efficient? Would it be really dumb to go with a 2 node setup? Is there a better solution?

Comment: What WAN bandwidth do you have between locations?

Comment: Not enough. I can use about 8-12 Mbit/s. More is available but then it will start competing with other stuff.

Comment: I used starwind vsan for wan replication of file server. It does only synchronous replication and with 12Mbit/s I doubt, that synchronous will work.

Comment: Synchronous replication across a WAN? OMG - bandwidth isn't the problem its latency.

Comment: What is the latency?

Comment: There’s no chance any sync solution would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lsyncd` to have a constant syncing of files between systems. `lsyncd` installs inotify watches on directories that are synced. Whenever files change in the directories, it will transfer changes to remote server using `rsync`.

Comment: Oooh - excitement. lsyncd looks like it fits the bill very well!

Comment: For the record, after sizing this, I would have needed gigabytes of memory just to track the files involved. The impact on file I/O would have been horrendous. While lsyncd works very well at the low Gb level it does not scale much beyond that.

Answer (score 5):

On the block level, the synchronization can be done using Starwind that makes a mirrored disk on both ends. It can run over iSCSI LUNs, making active-active storage. No additional hardware required. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/storage-ha-on-the-cheap-fixing-synology-diskstation-flaky-performance-with-starwind-free-part-3-failover-duration

On the file level, lsyncd and rsync do a mirror synchronizing files between servers. These tools might require tweaking the configuration files in order to ensure the file locking mechanism works as expected and no split-brain would occur. https://linoxide.com/tools/setup-lsyncd-sync-directories/

Comment: You provided a link to a document that describes high availability relying on a very fast link between the nodes. Not what I was asking about.

Comment: You can replicate with a close-to-WAN latencies using StarWind and lsyncd is 100% WAN friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ionice](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice%5D) for io load limit and *bwlimit* argument in rsync for limit network io.
There are also some other methods:
[Rsync huge dataset of small files 5TB, +M small files](https://serverfault.com/questions/914214/rsync-huge-dataset-of-small-files-5tb-m-small-files)

Comment: That's just going to slow it down but thanks for the link. Sadly ZFS on top of iscsi is even more difficult that on native disks.

Answer (score 0):

If you willing to try something new, then IPFS might be a great tool for you experiment with.

https://ipfs.io/

Using a Private IPFS Cluster might be give you great results depending on your file replication needs.

https://cluster.ipfs.io/

However bear in mind, this is pretty new stuff, but is maturing very quickly.

Comment: Ceph has been around a lot longer and is far better documented - but does not fit my use case.

Comment: As far as i know, IPFS has nothing to do with Ceph... But I hope you find something to fit your use case, or in-fact your limitation, it maybe that you may need to change the network architecture , bit the bullet and invested in some 10G switches and fibre, or change to a provider than can give you these things.. good luck.